# How to disable Swipe Gesture recognizer when a button is pressed?

Tags: ios, swift3, uiswipegesturerecognizer

I set up the recognizer like this:

```
    @IBAction func changeSeq(_ recognizer: UISwipeGestureRecognizer) {

    if (recognizer.direction == UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.left)
    {
    print ("nice")
    }
}
```

I need it disabled when the start button is pressed and enabled again when the pause is triggered. I don't want to disable all user interaction. How do I handle the swipe specifically?

Comment: Gesture recognizers have an `enabled` property you can set

Comment: Could you give an example, please.

Comment: @AntonPlatonov have you even tried to find the solution yourself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your start button `IBAction` code, set the gesture recognizer's `enabled` property to false, and in the pause button's `IBAction`, set `enabled = true`.

That's cleaner than setting the delegate to nil.

Comment: I have to bring it up again. I can't seem to be able to use this 'enabled' property. Do I absolutely need to set up delegate for each swipe to do this?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using swipe gesture delegates, change to **nil** and **self** according to button presses.

Comment: This works, but setting the enabled property on the gesture recognizer, as mentioned in Dan's comment, is cleaner and more intuitive.